# Basic javascript webscraper throws error / XPATH not resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I try to write a webscraper with the Puppeteers library. It worked properly on amazon.com - but with another page (coinhall.org) I get an error that I can't resolve.
Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

```
const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]');
const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
const rawTxt  = txt.jsonValue();
```

Error:

```
const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty')
```

Seems as if `el12` doesn't get its value somehow, right? Double checked the XPATH, it's correct though.

Comment: Added    `const waiting = await page.waitForXPath('....');` ... now it works. Seemingly the XPATH wasn't loaded in the DOM instantly